# Rails routing: How to create an unguessable route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, url-routing

I need somehow to make my routes non-guessable.

Actually a user finish the operation cycle (order status is finish) by making a get request via a QR-CODE reading.

But is pretty easy to 'guess' the route since the id is the same in the whole order life-cycle. The users can see the id in URL when the status is acepted (before finish).

So I was thinking to add a kind of random token to the url so they can't guess the route...

My routes are like this atm:

```rb
resources :orders, only: %i(create show index destroy edit update) do
    resources :reviews, only: %i(create new show index)
    resources :payments, only: %i(new create)
    member do
      post 'accept'
    end
    member do
      get 'read_qrcode'
    end
  end
```

Which generates this pattern to read_qrcode route:

`/orders/:id/read_qrcode`

So I was thinking to add any kind of token, maybe MD5 Hash, timestamp or whatever after read_qrcode and get a url like this:

`/orders/:id/read_qrcode/1a79a4d60de6718e8e5b326e338ae533`

How can I achieve this result, or maybe another solution to this?

Comment: Why would it be a problem that the URL is guessable? Is it a security concern?

Comment: It is a business concern. The user who generates the qrcode containing the route is a client of my product. The user that read the qrcode and make the request is a partner which is basically a freelancer working to my client. This route is to tell the application that the job was actually done so we can make the payment available to the partner. But right now he could guess the route and make the request without actually get it from the qrcode.

Comment: Can I suggest an improved title for this question. Refer to the fact you want to “create an unguessable route” as opposed to “avoid route guessing”. A small point; but better describes what you want. Route guessing could be the result of the developer not knowing the `rake routes` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the token the md5 of the concatenation of the ID and a secret.

So, let’s say the secret is “-no-guessing!”.

With an ID of 1, then md5(“1-no-guessing!) is `9493F2E821BA8B1FC791A048BBCD9A19`

And with ID 2, the token would be `AD17E6D3551BF0C0A2B0D5A029AEFBB2`

Those are legit MD5 hashes of the strings in the example, you should be able to verify that.

But I would need to know the secret to be able to generate this. Your app knows the secret, but your user does not.

When your orders#read_qrcode action is processed, pass the token as a get param (no need for it to be a path param). Then, have the controller generate the md5 of the concatenation of ID and the secret, comparing it with the token passed as a param

What I’ve described above is essentially an HMAC, where the “message” is the ID of the order. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC for more on HMACs

Answer (score 3):

Rails 6.1 also supports signed ids

```rb
order = Order.find(1)

Order.find_signed(order.signed_id)
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39313

https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/05/20/rails-6-1-adds-support-for-signed-ids-to-active-record.html

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would simply to use the `SecureRandom` library (already in Ruby Core), and to generate a unique token for each order.
It's quite easy to do that in a callback for example.

```
SecureRandom.hex(10) #=> "52750b30ffbc7de3b362"
```

Store the token in the record and check it while scanning the QR-Code in a `before_action`.